# Explanation for an atmospheric optical phenomenon

Tags: optics, scattering, refraction, atmospheric-science, diffraction

Consider the atmospheric optical phenomenon appearing in this [video](https://youtu.be/mwG8G4F1wPU?t=115). A screenshot at the appropriate time is shown below:

[image: screenshot showing the phenomenon]

The video is footage from a drone flying just above a low-lying, thin layer of wispy clouds, over an icy water body. In the otherwise pale white layer of cloudy vapors, we see a slightly brighter white vertical band flanked on either side with a brownish tinge (like NO$_2$), extending from the camera towards the horizon. Assuming the sun is behind the camera, the direction of the band is possibly the direction of incident sun rays, though I am not sure. The band moves as the drone moves.

What puzzles me is how to explain this within the framework of refraction and/or scattering from the suspended water droplets in the cloud. If this was caused by some sort of refraction and internal reflection, the motif should have been a circular bow with the camera at its center, like in [glory rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glory_(optical_phenomenon)) or a [fog bow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fog_bow). Also, that wouldn't explain the brown, and only brown, tinge flanking the band. Why is the central region of the band whitish? Why is there a band like brightness at all being cast on an otherwise dim cloud layer?

This is also reminiscent of a setting sun reflecting off the surface of an ocean, except in this analogy, the observer stands mid-ocean looking towards beach, back towards the sun. However, given how bluish the rest of the image is, it doesn't appear to be sunset and so that wouldn't explain the brownish tinge.

**How do we explain this?**

Answer (score 0):

If the ship doesn't move, from the previous points of view we can determine that the sunlight comes from its front side (with a small lean to starboard). So what we see from above the clouds is not the antisolar direction where we'd expect to see the glory, but rather to the right of the glory spot. And you can notice that the dark/light fringes are curved a bit, with the center being to the right of top/bottom parts.

So I think we are observing a [fogbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fog_bow), a bit non-uniform in width and location of the color fringes due to the clouds having non-uniform drop size distribution.